# Are these integrals $\int_{0}^\infty f(t)dt$, $\int_{-\infty}^0 f(-t)dt$ equal?

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> *Question about changing an integral bounds due to a reflection.*

Suppose you have an integral across $\Bbb R^{+}$ such that $$I=\int_{0}^\infty f(t)dt$$
Would $I$ be the same if I applied a reflection across the y-axis such that $t\to-t$ and integrated along $\Bbb R^{-}$ such that$$I=\int_{-\infty}^0 f(-t)dt$$
Is this ok?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you for your quick response(+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the change of variable, 
$$
u=-t, \qquad dt=-du, \qquad 0 \rightarrow 0,\qquad \infty \rightarrow -\infty,
$$ one gets
$$
I=\int_{0}^\infty f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{-\infty} f(-u)(-du)=\int_{-\infty}^0 f(-u)du,
$$ as announced.